# How can I make JWPlayer select default quality based on the bandwidth?

Tags: jwplayer, mpeg-dash

based on this artical: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428524-hd-quality-toggling

> The first quality in the list is the default and should be the lower
>   quality version of your file

How can I make JWPlayer select default quality based on the bandwidth?

Note: I'm using adaptive mpeg dash (mpd file)

Comment: With DASH, it will automatically select the best quality based on bandwidth. The article you are linking to is about HTTP progressive download, not streaming.

Comment: More information - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/2020482-about-dash-streaming, and - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/2020483-using-dash-streaming

Comment: Yes, I know with  DASH, it will automatically select the best quality based on bandwidth. but we can change quality form the button on the left corner. so how I can change the labels inside the button.

Comment: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/8566059